# QgsProcessingToolboxTreeView has been deleted

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I try to add the Google Satellite layer by adding it through Layers > Add Layer > XYZ Layer and using the URL `http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}` as the source. I then get an error popup, which says this (I include the full output in case somehow the path is important):

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsProcessingToolboxTreeView has been deleted 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/ProcessingPlugin.py", line 297, in sync_in_place_button_state
    self.toolbox.set_in_place_edit_mode(new_enabled_state and self.editInPlaceAction.isChecked())
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/ProcessingToolbox.py", line 133, in set_in_place_edit_mode
    self.algorithmTree.setFilters(filters)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsProcessingToolboxTreeView has been deleted


Python version: 3.8.7 (default, Feb 10 2021, 09:04:08) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.11-Hannover Hannover, 26cc1c762f 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/holtdwyer/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/holtdwyer/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/affine-2.3.0-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_contrib_python-4.3.0.36-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba-0.50.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cftime-1.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj-2.6.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.20.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.4-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio-1.1.5-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snuggs-1.4.7-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.13.post1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click_plugins-1.1.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/patsy-0.5.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python38.zip
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas-0.8.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/GDAL-3.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.5.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Rtree-0.9.4-py3.8.egg
/Users/holtdwyer/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/holtdwyer/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms
```

and the traceback shows the following cryptic message:

```
2022-03-24T20:22:43     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/ProcessingPlugin.py", line 297, in sync_in_place_button_state
      self.toolbox.set_in_place_edit_mode(new_enabled_state and self.editInPlaceAction.isChecked())
      File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/ProcessingToolbox.py", line 133, in set_in_place_edit_mode
      self.algorithmTree.setFilters(filters)
     RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsProcessingToolboxTreeView has been deleted
```

Other unrelated actions seem to also trigger this error, but not in a consistent way.

Comment: It doesn't address your question about the error, but you should be able to add the layer if you right-click *XYZ Tiles* in the Browser panel and choose *New Connection*